# css to fix the header of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a inner scrollbar and remove the outer scrollbar, so that the header is fixed and users can see the tabnames.When the data is more, inner scrollbar should appear to scroll the content in the page.I'm using bootstrap in my application. Any suggestions?
Please find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwrMLQGI1kRlzfb1Ropa?p=preview)

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="tabsctrl">

    <br><br>
<div>
 <div class="top-tabs">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
            <li role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)" >{{pg.tabName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

         <div class="tab-content">
          <!--Tab1 data div-->
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tabx">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!--heading here-->
                            </div>


                        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!--heading here-->
                            </div>

                            <div>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div>
                              asdasd
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I tried to include a css for tab-content. .tab-content{
        max-height: calc(100% - 120px);
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding: 0px 10% !important;
        margin-top: 60px !important;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set specific maximum height to your content and allow it to be scrollable with css:

```
max-height: 100px; 
overflow: scroll;
```

```html
<div ng-app="tabs">

  
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="tabsctrl">
    
    <br><br>
<div>
 <div class="top-tabs">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
            <li role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)" ></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
         <div class="tab-content">
          <!--Tab1 data div-->
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tabx">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!--heading here-->
                            </div>

                             
                        <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!--heading here-->
                            </div>

                            <div>
                            <div class="tab-content" style="max-height: 100px; overflow:scroll">
                                <div>
                              asdasd
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                
<!--//-->
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tabx">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!--heading here-->
                            </div>

                             
                        <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!--heading here-->
                            </div>

                            <div>
                            <div class="tab-content" style="max-height: 100px; overflow:scroll">
                                <div>
                              asdasd
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div> </div>
            </div> </div>
```

Comment: When I applied as stated above, the area to show the content is minimized compared to the page size. Please find the http://plnkr.co/edit/wILC0gjKa2PjJQEdlm7t?p=preview . In the demo, i have one tab-content div, first it should occupy the page then it show the scrollbar if more data exists.